# JSON parse request format

Tags: javascript, json

```js
{
  "ticker": {
    "high": 915,
    "low": 890,
    "avg": 902.5,
    "vol": 5066998.70873,
    "vol_cur": 5587.67867,
    "last": 906.99,
    "buy": 906.989,
    "sell": 904.012,
    "updated": 1485237212,
    "server_time": 1485237213
  }
}
```

I thought the appropriate way to format would be:

```
price = ticker.ticker.last;
```

But this isn't working. Could anyone try to explain/point me in the right direction of why that format wouldn't work?

I've looked at other examples on the internet and I was led to think this should work.

EDIT: Heres some of my code:

```
function getbtcPrice(){    
var btcprice = new XMLHttpRequest();
btcprice.open('GET', 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker', true);
btcprice.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(btcprice.readyState == 4){
    var ticker = JSON.parse(btcprice.responseText);
    var price = ticker.ticker.last;
}
}
btcprice.send();
console.log(price);
}
getbtcPrice();
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rbsu9yjc/)

Comment: Can you check the type of first ticker? Try `Array.isArray(ticker)` to check if its an array.

Comment: Try `var ticker = {
  "ticker": {
    "high": 915,
    "low": 890,
    "avg": 902.5,
    "vol": 5066998.70873,
    "vol_cur": 5587.67867,
    "last": 906.99,
    "buy": 906.989,
    "sell": 904.012,
    "updated": 1485237212,
    "server_time": 1485237213
  }
}` and assign it to a variable.

Comment: @HarishKommuri not sure if that will help. I bet OP has already done that. Notice `ticker.ticker`

Comment: Yea, I used "..." to simulate alot more code

Comment: I put my code in some example code

Answer (score 0):

Correct form of JSON

```
{"ticker":{"high":"915","low":"890","avg":"902.5","vol":"5066998.70873","vol_cur": "5587.67867","last": "906.99","buy": "906.989","sell": "904.012","updated":"1485237212","server_time": "1485237213"}}
```

JSON keeps everything in double quotes. And to process it you need to parse it.
Thanks, Good Luck

Comment: I got this from https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker and I do parse it but let me try playing around with it more